# How to compare textbox value to txt file

Tags: vb.net, textbox

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim linenumber0 As Integer
    linenumber0 = 0
    Dim mass As Double
    mass = (File.ReadAllLines("225.txt").ElementAt(linenumber0).ToString)
    If (Math.Abs((cDbl(TextBox1.Text) - mass < 0.5) Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
```

Im getting an error conversing from string to double is not valid. It is probably a simple solution but i cant see it right now

Comment: When you assign the value to mass, it is still a string. You should convert it to a double with cDbl. also you don't have enough closing brackets for your if statement (4 opening brackets and 2 closing brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because the data read from the file is a `String`, however you are attempting to assign it to a variable declared as `Double`.
You can use `TryParse` to convert the `String` to `Double`, avoid errors and provide appropriate feedback.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lineNumber0 As Integer
    Dim mass As Double
    Dim input As Double

    If Double.TryParse(File.ReadAllLines("225.txt").ElementAt(linenumber0), mass) Then
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, input) AndAlso Math.Abs(input - mass) < 0.5 Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    Else
        'Bad file input
    End If
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering, the code works right now but when I put 10.2 as an input number, and 10 is mass, textbox is still not green,even tho the difference is less than 0.5. It seems like it doesnt recognize the input as double, so maybe you know where could the problem be

Comment: You should debug your code to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you set the value to mass is catching a String, so parse it with a simple CDbl, like this

```
mass = cDbl(File.ReadAllLines("225.txt").ElementAt(linenumber0).ToString)
```

I supose that with this fix it will works.
Just in case, surround it with a TRY CATCH in case what it reads is not valid